# How to get powercfg -requests information without admin privilages

Tags: windows, powershell, screensaver

I'm currently working on a screensaver application for Windows that needs to check if a user is idle so it knows when to turn on. Sometimes a user may have a certain app (like a video player) running that requires no user input and idles the system even though the system isn't truly idle.

The `powercfg -requests` command displays if any application has requested the display to stay active, but requires administrator privileges to run. I looked at the official `powercfg` documentation and played with a few commands in Power Shell and cound'lt find anything that worked. Is there a way to get this same information somehow without the application requiring administrator privileges?